# DXF export from QGIS is not exporting all features

Tags: qgis, export, dxf

I'm trying to export multiple layers from QGIS 2.18 to DXF format for opening in CAD.

I am using the native DXF Exporter (Project -> DXF Export).

Here are the parameters I'm setting:

[image]

And the result in CAD does not contain all of this.

At a guess, it only seems to be exporting line layers and ignoring the polygons? Although this seems odd.

Can anyone suggest why I am losing features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly there's been a few related fixes since 2.18. it's worth upgrading to a later version and retesting.

Answer (score 1):

Are the objects present at all in AutoCAD if you Select All? If they're present but not visible, try changing your symbology scale setting in the QGIS dxf output window to 1:500 or 1:1000 or something meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

When exporting dxf for AutoCAD, I usually save the shapefile as dxf and - if needed - merge layers in CAD.

If I do need attributes to be carried over, I use Arc2CAD (proprietary software).